# In java find substring between ocurrences

Tags: java, string

In java, how can I find the sub string from second/nth occurrence of an expression till its third/n+1 occurrence in a String.

Something like this:

life;;is;;beautiful;;world is in a **list**

**Result:**

```
beautiful
```

Comment: downvoters please leave a comment,let the OP know where and what is the reason

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  I mean *besides* asking us.

Comment: Try to follow this guidance before you ask: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve it using split(). Following is the code that prints the output you want.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "life;;is;;beautiful;;world";
    int n=2;
    String[] strArray = str.split(";;");
    System.out.println(strArray[n]);
}
```

Hope this will solve your purpose.

Comment: this is better..:)..though it could throw indexoutofbound exception..

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `subString(start,end)`

Ex.

```
String s="India Is Great";
String s1=s.subString(1,4);
```

Now, You can check the required String in s1.

it will be **ndi**

Comment: String s = "patriotism;;sucks;;hardly;  
String[] tokens = s.split(";;);  
String result = tokens[2];

Comment: This is just a usual sample string i do work with. @Gab

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to get, but if you know that the list is separated by two semicolons (;;) then split the string and obtain the values from an array that you get